# ASP.NET MVC Select Drop Down list, set the default value and retrieve the selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select

The answer I am sure is simple. I have a `<select>` with a list of values. For edit mode, I want the drop down to show the current value and have the selected when the view renders. And also when the form is submitted take a possible new selected value and pass it back to the controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

From the view:

```
<td style="padding:15px">
    <label asp-for="OrganizationTypeId" class="form-control-label" style="font-weight:bold">Organization</label>
    <select asp-for="OrganizationTypeId" class="form-control" style="width:450px" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.orgTypes, "Id", "OrganizationName"))">
        <option value="" disabled hidden selected>Select Organization....</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Code in the controller:

```
dr = _electedOfficials.getDeputyReg(jurisdictionId, Id);

dr.orgTypes = _electedOfficials.GetOrganizationTypes(jurisdictionId);

return View(dr);
```

OrgTypes class

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is preparing list of the `SelectListItem` and return the  selected item `Id` to the controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ...
    dr.orgTypes = _electedOfficials.GetOrganizationTypes(jurisdictionId);

    var model = dr.orgTypes.Select(d => new SelectListItem() { Selected = (d.Id == /* id of default selection*/), Text = d.OrganizationName, Value = d.Id.ToString() }).ToList(); 

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? seletedId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && seletedId.HasValue)
    {
        // Processing the selected value...
    }           
    return RedirectToAction("Index");           
}
```

In the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("OrgTypesList");
        $("#SeletedId").val(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    });

    function changefunc(val) {
        $("#SeletedId").val($("#OrgTypesList").val());
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @* To pass `SeletedId` to controller *@
    <input id="SeletedId" name="SeletedId" type="hidden" />

    <label asp-for="OrganizationTypeId" class="form-control-label" style="font-weight:bold">Organization</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("OrgTypesList", Model, "Select Organization...", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "changefunc(this.value)" })

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```